# possibilities of the picture environment

Tags: diagrams

from what I could find on the net, the picture environment does not offer the triangle shape. It is possible to get something similar with lines but not when you want the triangle to be fill up with a solid color. Do you confirm? Maybe the bezier curves could be an option.

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{2pt}
\begin{picture}(50,200)
\linethickness{1pt}
\bezier{20}(0,0)(10,30)(50,30)
\put(0,0){\circle*{1}}
\put(50,30){\line(-1,0){40}}
\put(50,31){\makebox(0,0)[b]{C}}
\end{picture}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`picture` environment is too old to use. You'd better use `TikZ` or `PSTricks` instead, which are the most powerful packages to draw pictures. And if you are so familar with standard `picture` environment that you don't want to change, you can also use `pict2e` to improve the standard `picture` environment.

Examples:

In `TikZ`,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=orange,line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (4,3) -- (5,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In `PSTricks`,

```
\begin{pspicture}(5,4)
\pspolygon[linewidth=1pt,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange]
  (0,0)(4,3)(5,0)
\end{pspicture}
```

In `pict2e`

```
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}
\begin{picture}(5,4)
{\color{orange}\polygon*(0,0)(4,3)(5,0)}
{\linethickness{1pt}\polygon(0,0)(4,3)(5,0)}
\end{picture}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. I know it is old and I'm using it in a very limited manner. I like the `pict2e` package.